# Set DataView (or DataTable.DefaultView) RowFilter for a custom type

Tags: c#, .net, rowfilter, custom-type

I'm developing an application on the datagridview filtering. I'm using RowFilter property of the dataview for the filtering data. My database table contains int & varchar data type fields. And I want to use "LIKE" query in the RowFilter Property for filtering the dataview but the "LIKE" is used only for the string data type and not for int data type. So I want to convert the `int` datatype field to the `varchar` datatype, but I don't want to alter my table structure. I just want the datatype to be changed temporary for my filtering condition only.

Can anybody help me in resolving this problem?

```
string colname="ProductID";
string condition="111";
DataView dv = new DataView();
dv.Table = ds.Tables[0] ;
dv.RowFilter ="CAST ("+colname+" AS TEXT) LIKE '"+ condition+"%'"  ;
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The RowFilter is being carried out by .NET, not SQL Server. It supports a limited set of expressions which are described in the Framework documentation.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx

You should be able to use LIKE as well as CONVERT, but unlike SQL server, it wants a .NET type.

```
dv.RowFilter ="CONVERT("+colname+", System.String) LIKE '"+ condition+"%'"  ;
```

Comment: I've tried ur code but it gives an error as "Invalid type name 'String' "

Comment: Try *System.String*.  I've updated the answer.  Also, read the documentation.

Comment: Thanks very much. I had the exact same error, and I would never figure it out my self that the filtering was actually being carried by .NET and not by SQL CE.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast the integer...

```
  SELECT * FROM table WHERE CAST(field AS TEXT) LIKE '%123%'
```

Comment: i've tried ur code but it gives the error as "The expression contains undefined function call CAST()".

Comment: yes i'm using SQL server. But i think you have not read my question carefully.

Comment: I think I understand it, but you can't cast to varchar, I don't think. There isn't a space after your CAST, is there?

Answer (score -1):

you can use either

```
Convert(varchar(20),value)
```

or

```
cast(value is varchar)
```

Comment: but it gives error as "The expression contains undefined function call varchar()."