# Error "Cannot perform Like Operation on 'System.Int32' and 'System.String'" setting DataGridView data source

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have created a data grid view in a Windows application using Visual Studio and I am trying to query it with a search text box. The field is a series of numbers but I have it set up for `Varchar(10)`.

When I use the command below I get the following error

> Cannot perform Like Operation on 'System.Int32' and 'System.String'

Code:

```
DataView DV = new DataView(dbdataset);
DV.RowFilter = string.Format("JobNumber Like '%{0}%' ", textBox1.Text);
dataGridView1.DataSource = DV;
```

Thanks

Comment: I guess the JobNumber column is of type int?

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: `Otto` the OP states that the datatype is of type `varchar(10)`

Comment: I am using MySQL and JobNumber is the PrimKey in the DB

Comment: @DJKRAZE, the `jobnumber` column of the dataview is an int32 type.  If it were string there would be no error

Comment: then this statement in his question `The field is a series of numbers but I have it set up for Varchar(10)` is misleading

Comment: @DJKRAZE, yes, I'm not sure what he means by that.  Unless OP's searching a field other than `jobnumber` that is a varchar(10), i dont know.

Comment: you could also try to Parse the value of textbox1.Text 
`int jobNum;` 
`if (Int32.TryParse(textBox1.Text, jobNum){}` then pass jobNum in your search also can you do JobNumber = vs jobNumber LIKE are there unique job numbers..?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Cast the `JobNumber` to a string before you do a like.

```
DV.RowFilter = string.Format("convert(JobNumber, 'System.String') Like '%{0}%' ",
                             textBox1.Text);
```

DataViews can take [many different options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(VS.80).aspx) in their filters.

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5125575/2589202), the filtering is taking place by .NET and the DataView, not by MySql

Comment: That did not crash the app, but it also did not query it

Comment: @dane, lets just clear a few things up.  You want to search `jobnumber` right?  Its an integer primary key right?  What are some example values of `jobnumber`? Why do you say `varchar(10)` in your question?

Comment: also try hard coding it initially to test if it works for example `DV.RowFilter = "jobNumber LIKE '1234'"` for example and see if it works if not then there is something else wrong

Comment: @DJKRAZE, that would just duplicate his original problem.  `JobNumber`, if an int, needs to be converted to a string in order to use a `like` operator.  If OP were to try `jobnumber = 1234` that would work without conversion.

Comment: that's why I asked if he could do JobNumber = vs jobNumber Like

Comment: paqogomez, First Thanks. I would like to search JobNumber it is a varchar because the job number will not always be a digit occasionally it will have a letter in it.  I have an input Form that populates a MySQL dataset, sometime the job number is 1,2,500 or a500, etc.  I would like a text box to be able to jump the row with the JobNumber being called in to question.

Comment: DJ Kraze, JobNumber is the name of the field.

Comment: show us the database Schema.. I know that jobNumber is a Field but you're confusing us on the DataType here...

Comment: *in the dataview* what is the column type of `jobnumber`?  It wont be `varchar(10)` because that is a database type.  I want to know the type of the column in the VIEW, not the database.

Comment: @DJKRAZE, the schema is only important if OP wants to change the sql, not filter the dataview.

Comment: this throws an error when my column header has an space character in it, when I use [ and ] to eliminate it, the CONVERT command is ignored. I've searched and got nothing. It's pretty frustrating, any ideas?

Comment: @ParSa, been a long time since i wrote this.  the gist of this is that the string needs to evaluate to a proper query.  So if `"convert([Job Number], 'System.String') Like '%{0}%' "` doesnt work, then braces are not the right way to encase spaces.  Perhaps `\[` (backslash brace)?  Not sure.  Probably easier to remove spaces.